# Use of NSDocument when I don't need multiple document support?

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data, nsdocument

I like NSDocument because, when used in conjunction with a Core Data model, gives me an application with persistent data for free. But I know that, for my particular project, I will only ever deal with one "document." I don't need the multiple document support that comes with the document architecture stack. Does it make sense for me to still use NSDocument, but break multiple document support where ever I find it? Or is there a better way to get the persistent magic I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aren't creating a document-based application, there is a default project template in Xcode that gives you core data without the document stack. It will automatically create an app delegate for you that implements the core data persistence layer.

Comment: This seems so obvious now! Thanks for the answer.